# Migrating Quartz code to 2.2.x

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I've been working on changing our Quartz code from 1.8.6 to 2.x.x.  As you probably know, in Quartz 2, there are a lot of API changes. One of the problems I'm trying to fix is to schedule jobs. Previously, the code looked like this:

```
private JobSchedule scheduleExistingJob(JobSchedule schedule) throws SchedulerException
{
  JobInfo jobInfo = schedule.getJobInfo();

  Trigger trigger = QuartzUtils.createTriggerFromJobSchedule(schedule);

  trigger.setJobName(jobInfo.getName());
  trigger.setJobGroup(jobInfo.getGroup());
  DateTime nextRunDateTime = new DateTime(m_scheduler.scheduleJob(trigger));
  JobSchedule newSched = updateScheduleNextRunDateTime(schedule, nextRunDateTime);
  return newSched;
}
```

With this old code, there are two syntax errors: one on `trigger.setJobName(jobInfo.getName());` and the other on `trigger.setJobGroup(jobInfo.getGroup());`

Both are complaining that `The method setJobName(String) is undefined for the type Trigger`. No surprise there.

I'm trying to figure out how to make this compatible in Quartz 2.x and this is what I've come up with so far:

```
private JobSchedule scheduleExistingJob(JobSchedule schedule) throws SchedulerException
{
  JobInfo jobInfo = schedule.getJobInfo();

  JobDetail job = newJob()
      .withIdentity(jobInfo.getName(), jobInfo.getGroup())
      .build();

  Trigger trigger = QuartzUtils.createTriggerFromJobSchedule(schedule);

  Trigger t = newTrigger()
      .forJob(job)
      .build(); 

  DateTime nextRunDateTime = new DateTime(m_scheduler.scheduleJob(trigger));
  JobSchedule newSched = updateScheduleNextRunDateTime(schedule, nextRunDateTime);
  return newSched;
}
```

I can't figure out how to incorporate the job info/group with the trigger.  It seems that in the new API I can't specify a generic trigger, it has to be either a Cron or a Simple. I may be over thinking everything too.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i am also stuck with the same issue please help

Answer (score 0):

Try to use next migration manual: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/migration-guide